# generating grid/nested list "n" by "n"

Tags: python, nested-lists

So my issaue here is that I am trying to make a nested list that is of equal width and height, that is filled with random integers between 1 and 100.

The code I have is :

And my error is that type int is not subscriptable for the like output += ......

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

```
import random

def generateRandomGrid(n):

    randomList = []
    for i in range(n) :
        randomList.append(random.randint(1,100))
    for i in range(n):
        output=random.randint(1,100)
        for j in range(n):
            output+= str(randomList[i][j]) + random.randint(1,100)
        print(output)

def main() :

    print(generateRandomGrid(5))
main()
```

Comment: this line `output+= str(randomList[i][j]) + random.randint(1,100)` produce the error because `randomList` is a list of integers because your are added integers (`randomList.append(random.randint(1, 100))`) and not an another list

Answer (score 5):

list comprehensions are your friend:

```
grid = [[randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)]
```

into a function:

```
def generate_random_grid(n):
    return [[randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

more elegant:

```
def generate_random_grid(size, min=1, max=100):
    return [[randint(min, max) for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
```

**Note:**
If using python 2.7 or older change `range` for `xrange`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you want a list where width and heigth are equal.

```
import random

def generateRandomGrid(n):
    randomList = []
    for i in range(n) :
        num = random.randint(1,100)
        randomList.append([num, num])
    return randomList


def main() :
    print(generateRandomGrid(5))

main()
```

Ouput:
`[[92, 92], [8, 8], [10, 10], [37, 37], [11, 11]]`

Comment: Your width and height are not equal. I think the question is to have an nxn grid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you look for:

```
from random import randint
n= 4
rand_matrix = [ [ randint(0, 100) for none in range(n)] for none in range(n)]

print(rand_matrix)
#=> [[49, 29, 15, 52], [6, 34, 19, 99], [91, 29, 83, 60], [13, 32, 95, 81]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to use numpy's random integer function, so

```
import numpy as np
def generateRandomGrid(n):
    return np.random.randint(1,101,(n,n)).tolist()
```